# Can TileStache use external tilestache.cfg file?

Tags: tilestache, configuration

I have a need for an ever evolving tilestache.cfg file.  I would like to be able to load this from an external source.  Is it possible to run a Tilestache server with

`tilestache-server.py -c http://s3.amazonaws.com/*myBucket*/tilestache.cfg`

or even with

`gunicorn --workers 4 "TileStache:WSGITileServer('http://s3.amazonaws.com/*myBucket*/tilestache.cfg')"

Or am I completely off base here?

Answer (score 1):

So after learning a lot about TileStache in last several days I found this tidbit sitting in the Config.py file:

> Although a configuration file can be parsed from a remote URL, some
>           paths (e.g. the location of a disk cache) must be local to the server.
>           In cases where we mix a remote configuration location with a local
>           cache location, e.g. "http://example.com/tilestache.cfg", the disk path
>           must include the "file://" prefix instead of an ambiguous absolute
>           path such as "/tmp/tilestache".

Interesting, so it appears that yes, one can very well use a tilestach.cfg file sitting in S3 (or anywhere else that is web accessible) BUT you must include the **file://** prefix in the cache: settings in the tilestache.cfg file.

So the following will not work:

```
{    
    "cache": {
        "name": "Test",
        "path": "/tmp/tiles",
        "umask": "0000"
    },
    "layers": {...}
}
```

While the following did work for me:

```
{
    "cache": {
        "name": "Test",
        "path": "file:///tmp/stache",
        "umask": "0000"
    },
    "layers": {...}
}
```

Also I learned the mod_python is dead, which is a shame as it was awesome when it came to re-reading the tilestach.cfg file every time the http://webserver/tile/tile.py/layer/z/x.png urls are requested.  This was fantastic for our clients ever changing maps.  But with TileStache running via a WSGI and mod_wsgi all it takes is to run a 'touch' command on the .wsgi file to force Tilestache to re-read its tilestach.cfg.

Now if I can only figure out how to get this tile server to run inside an aws auto scaling group I might be able to meet our clients' demands . . .